# standard error of a correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics

I would like to establish the proof for the standard error of a correlation coefficient. Assume that we have two iid samples $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ We know that the sample correlation is given by

$$\text{SCor(X,Y)}=\frac{\sum_i (X_i - \bar X ) ( Y_i - \bar Y) }{\sqrt{\sum_i (X_i - \bar X )^2 \times \sum_i (Y_i - \bar Y )^2}} $$

**I would like to avoid distributional assumptions until they are absolutely required.** I am struggling to disentangle the products in the expectation to find the first and second moments of the sample correlation. Ultimately of course I am searching for the square root of the variance of the sample correlation.

This post is based on the definition found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Definition) and I would like to contribute to that page if possible because this is an issue too rarely addressed. Please excuse me if this is too elementary.

Comment: OP wrote: `We know that the sample correlation ... is an unbiased estimator ... of Cor(X,Y)` ................... Really? How do 'we' _know_ this??? I know it not.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, I was under the false impression that it was. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: So, you have scor = `numerator`/Sqrt[`denominator`]. The numerator is a symmetric polynomial in power sums, so we can find the moments of the numerator; the same is true for `denominator`. However, Sqrt[`denominator`] is not a symmetric polynomial in power sums, so I don't believe you will be able to find a general solution for that. And the ratio is not a symmetric polynomial either ... so I don't believe you will be able to find a general solution for that either.